# Write data on a .txt file (C language)

Tags: c, file

I want to write in a .txt file, an area information, and work with dynamic vectors. 
I have a header with these structures:

```
struct area{
   // struct n_area * prox;
     char nome[20];
     int peso;
     int pesoatual;
     int jaula;
     int nareas;
     char **vizinhos;

};
typedef struct area AREA;
typedef AREA *PAREA;
```

and the function:

```
PAREA criaArea(){
    PAREA area;
    area = (PAREA)malloc(sizeof(AREA));
    printf("Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", area->nome);
    printf("Capacidade: ");
    scanf("%d", &area->peso);
    area->peso = 0;

    return  area;
}
```

What I want to show on the file: 
Area (name), Capacity (kg) and the adjacent areas.
It's giving me these errors:

```
funcoes.c: At top level:
funcoes.c:65:7: error: conflicting types for 'criaArea'
 PAREA criaArea(){
       ^
funcoes.c:38:22: note: previous implicit declaration of 'criaArea' was here
             case 49: criaArea(); break;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error of conflicting types for 'criaArea' means that there are two different declarations of 'criaArea'. Thus ensuring that the declarations of ''criaArea' are same with each other   is the key to fix the error of conflicting types.  But  your error does not seem to be caused by this reason(conflicting types). I think this error may be caused by wrong order of including head file in the C file. Please show the more code if you can.  Are declarations and definitions of the function criaArea  defined separately in header file(.h) and C file(.c). Sorry for poor English! I hope that can help you!

Comment: @Vasco Cardoso : If you are calling this function in the same file you declare it in, make sure you have a function prototype.  Otherwise the function is "implicitly declared" to return int, and that will conflict with the definition which returns PAREA.

Comment: I agree with you. The best way is that declarations of functions or C struct type  prototype  should be put in the C head file(.h) and definitions of functions should be put in the C file(.c). Then   including the head file in the C file before you use these functions(including call or define the functions).

Comment: Thanks guys, @WangYang you're right, it was the order of the functions ahah